# hacerlo sin jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html

quiero hacer lo siguiente sin la necesidad de jquery, este cogido me genera una palabra aleatoria de la db y js lo llama a la etiqueta p

```
<div>
<form action="js/js.js" method="post" name="frm">
<input type="button" name="catga" value="new word" class="b" onclick="boton();">
</form>
</div>
<div id="dos"><p id="worda"></p></div>
```

el codigo js el cual me muestra la palabra en la etiqueta p

```
function boton() {

$(document).ready(function() {

var pal="#worda";

$(pal).load("./php/php.php");

});
return false;
};
```

codigo php el cual escoge una palabra de la db aleatoria

```
include("conexion.php");
$codigo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria_a")or die(mysqli_error()); 
mt_srand(time()); 
$max = mysql_num_rows($codigo); 
$rand = mt_rand(1,$max); 
$obtener = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria_a WHERE codigo_A='$rand'"); 
while($ban = mysql_fetch_array($obtener)) { 

echo $ban['palabra_A']; }
```

es para no usar jquery plis gente, puede que jquery lo simplifique pero para no estar trabajando con un archivo pesado plis

Comment: ya puse la función del código, gracias por leer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

equivalencias:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // código
});
```

se traduce a:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // código
 });
```

el `$.load` lo podes hacer de un par de maneras, la mas aconsejable actualmente es usar `fetch` y promesas (si pasa tal entonces tal)

Todo junto quedaría algo asi:

```js
var boton = function() {
  fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
      document.querySelector('#worda').innerHTML = body;
    });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   boton();
});
```

```html
<div>
<form action="js/js.js" method="post" name="frm">
<input type="button" name="catga" value="new word" class="b" onclick="boton();">
</form>
</div>
<div id="dos"><p id="worda"></p></div>
```

**Nota:** estás usando un on document load dentro de una funcion de click de un boton, `#worda` se cargaría al inicio o cada vez que presionas el boton? en el ejemplo pongo ambas, se llama a `boton()` al cargar el DOM y luego a cada click (la url trae texto aleatorio)

Comment: no carga al inicio, solo carga cuando presiono el botón, gracias me ayudo mucho