# Problema con propiedad de CSS para hacer scroll

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un chat, y como saben, tengo que hacer que de alguna manera donde se ven los mensajes se pueda hacer scroll. Para eso tengo la propiedad overflow y le pongo el valor auto, pero este no muestra el ultimo mensaje una vez que es enviado, hay que hacer scrolldown, y yo quiero que no tengas que hacer scrolldown para que se muestre. No se si me doy a entender.

Comment: Para que te puedas dar a entender mejor publica el código de tu avance y una explicación breve del mismo

Comment: Hola Diesan, deberías añadir un [mcve] para ver tu problema y poder ayudarte de manera concreta con lo que necesites. Con lo que has puesto ahora mismo, sabemos cuál es el problema, pero sin el código es difícil darte una respuesta precisa. Lee [ask] para más información y edita la pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Tendrías que igualar el `scrollTop` al `scrollHeight`, algo así :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let boton = document.getElementById("dale");
  dale.onclick = function() {
    var chatDiv = document.getElementById("loMensaje");
    var newEl = document.createElement('p');
    newEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Nuevo mensaje!' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)));
    chatDiv.appendChild(newEl);
    chatDiv.scrollTop = chatDiv.scrollHeight;
  }
});
```

```css
.contenedor {
  position: relative;
}

#loMensaje {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 480px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <button id="dale">chat me plz</button>
  <div id="loMensaje">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Comment: Como podría hacer eso con jquery? osea, ese document.addEventListener()  como lo haria? algo asi $document.(DOMContentLoaded, function(){...})

Comment: esa primera linea es equivalente a `$(document).ready(function(){` ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177710/hacerlo-sin-jquery/177716#177716