# ¿Cómo hacer que la scrollbar se desplace hacia abajo automáticamente?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo 3 cuadrados, uno naranja, uno azul y otro morado. El cuadrado azul se mueve con el morado pero al moverlo hacia abajo hay un punto en el que se crea una scrollbar y el cuadrado azul no se sale del naranja, pero el morado si se sale porque no esta dentro del naranja. Lo que quiero es que el cuadrado morado no se salga del naranja. Y para ello pensé en bajar la scrollbar automáticamente y así que no se salga porque cuando bajo la scrollbar me muestra el cuadrado morado dentro del naranja.
Este es mi código:

```js
let a = document.getElementById("ej1");
let b = document.getElementById("ej2");
a.addEventListener("mousedown", moverelemento);
b.style.left = a.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
b.style.top = a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 66 + "px";
document.getElementById("ej").addEventListener("scroll", encuadrar);
function encuadrar(){
    b.style.left = a.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
    b.style.top = a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 66 + "px";
}
function moverelemento(e) {
  const X = e.clientX - a.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const Y = e.clientY - a.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  a.ondragstart = function () { return false; }
  function mover(pageX, pageY) {
    a.style.left = pageX - X + 'px';
    a.style.top = pageY - Y + 'px';
    b.style.left = a.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
    b.style.top = a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 66 + "px";
  }
  function posicionar(event) {
    mover(event.pageX, event.pageY);
  }
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', posicionar);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', eliminar);
  function eliminar(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', posicionar);
  }
}
```

```css
#ej {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: orange;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

#ej1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: -16px;
}

#ej2 {
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ej">
  <p id="ej1"></p>
</div>
<p id="ej2"></p>
```

(Mejor pruébenlo en pantalla completa)

Encontre que existía esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo
para hacer que la scrollbar se desplazase y así evitar que el cuadrado morado se saliera.
Pero intentando ponerlo en mi código sigue sin hacer lo que yo quiero.

Si no se entiende porfavor díganmelo.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que no estás seguro sobre la pregunta. ¿Mover la scrollbar hacia abajo? Si el cuadrado morado está arriba. ¿No será que quieres que el cuadrado permanezca siempre en la pantalla? En ese caso, usa `position: fixed` en css

Comment: Es la scrollbar del cuadrado naranja. Igual no he formulado bien. El cuadrado morado esta arriba, pero cuando yo muevo el cuadrado azul, que se mueve con el morado llega un punto en el que llega al final del cuadrado naranja, y se crea una scrollbar. El cuadrado azul se queda dentro del naranja, pero el morado no, porque no esta dentro del naranja. Y lo que quería hacer para que el morado no se saliese en ese punto era bajar la scrollbar del elemento naranja para que se quedara dentro.

Comment: Me faltaba un poco de código, igual por eso tampoco se entendía, espero que ahora si se entienda. Gracias!

Comment: if azultop +azul height > naranja height -> naranja scroll to ( azul top + azul height) ; o limitar el movimiento cuando azultop +azul height > naranja height

Comment: btw si lo vas a limitar conviene setear el left o top con un Math.max( nueva x o y, (ancho o alto del contenedor) - ( ancho o alto del movible ) asi no hay tanto if

Comment: hay algo parecido en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183212/81450

Comment: He intentado hacerlo con lo del scrollto pero no se porque no funciona el scrollto

Comment: Y otra cosa lo de  igualar el scrollTop al scrollHeight tendria que ponerlo en la funcion mover o en la de encuadrar? Lo he puesto en la funcion mover pero tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definis ap como el parent del div a

```
ap = a.parentElement;
```

Luego al mover te fijas si los boundaries se escapan "se van de boundary" o en otras palabras si el borde derecho ( o borde inferior ) del elemento movible/movido es mayor o igual al borde derecho ( o borde inferior ) del elemento contenedor.

Si eso pasa le decis al scroll del contenedor que se ponga al máximo posible.

```
if (
  a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= ap.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
) {
  ap.scrollTop = ap.scrollHeight;
}
```

```
if (
  a.getBoundingClientRect().right >= ap.getBoundingClientRect().right
) {
  ap.scrollLeft = ap.scrollWidth;
}
```

```js
let a = document.getElementById("ej1");
let b = document.getElementById("ej2");
a.addEventListener("mousedown", moverelemento);
b.style.left = a.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
b.style.top = a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 66 + "px";
document.getElementById("ej").addEventListener("scroll", encuadrar);

ap = a.parentElement;

function encuadrar() {
  b.style.left = a.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
  b.style.top = a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 66 + "px";
}

function moverelemento(e) {
  const X = e.clientX - a.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const Y = e.clientY - a.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  a.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  }

  function mover(pageX, pageY) {
    a.style.left = pageX - X + 'px';
    a.style.top = pageY - Y + 'px';
    b.style.left = a.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
    b.style.top = a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 66 + "px";

    if (a.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= ap.getBoundingClientRect().bottom) {
      ap.scrollTop = ap.scrollHeight;
    }

    if (a.getBoundingClientRect().right >= ap.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
      ap.scrollLeft = ap.scrollWidth;
    }

  }

  function posicionar(event) {
    mover(event.pageX, event.pageY);
  }
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', posicionar);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', eliminar);

  function eliminar(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', posicionar);
  }
}
```

```css
#ej {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: orange;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

#ej1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: -16px;
}

#ej2 {
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ej">
  <p id="ej1"></p>
</div>
<p id="ej2"></p>
```

Comment: Grax! Ya entendí