# Actualizar automáticamente la diferencia en minutos para cada fila - PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Estoy algo bloqueado en esto y me gustaría recibir una ayuda. Tengo una tabla MySQL con la siguiente información:

| created | users | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-01 13:00:00 | anna | 85.00 |
| 2018-08-01 11:23:00 | alfred | 35.00 |
| 2018-08-01 17:04:00 | georgy | 125.00 |
| 2018-08-01 19:30:00 | linda | 42.00 |
| 2018-08-01 08:35:00 | alex | 76.00 |
| 2018-08-01 10:29:00 | john | 94.00 |
| 2018-08-01 15:27:00 | hugo | 75.30 |

Quiero obtener la diferencia en minutos entre la fecha actual y la columna start_session para cada fila en una tabla HTML, así que mi código es el siguiente:

```
<table class="table">
<tr><td><b>Minutes</b></td><td><b>User - Points</b></td></tr>
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  $date = date(Y-m-d H:i:s);

  if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res){
    $start_session = $row['created'];

      $start_date = new DateTime($start_session);
      $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($date));
      $minutes = $since_start->days * 24 * 60;
      $minutes += $since_start->h * 60;
      $minutes += $since_start->i;
 ?>
 <tr>
  <td>
      <?php echo $minutes." min"; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
      <?php echo $row['users']." - ".$row['points']." points"; ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
<?php
  }
 }
?>         
</table>
```

Hasta aquí está funcionando bien, pero necesito actualizar la página para actualizar a su vez la cantidad de minutos transcurridos y yo deseo que esto sea en tiempo real, se que AJAX puede ser una opción junto con SetInterval pero sólo quiero actualizar la columna de los minutos y no volver a escribir toda la tabla con la información. ¿Cómo lo puedo resolver?

Agradeceré su respuesta.

Comment: Creo que lo mas fácil y sencillo que puedes hacer, es convertir las dos fechas a timestamp y restar la diferencia, después que tengas los segundos los divides entre 60, para obtener los minutos de diferencia que hay entre las dos fechas.   seria asi, convertir timestamp -> obtener diferencia -> convertir segundos a minutos

Comment: @DarckBlezzer Gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo que necesito es que se actualice esa cantidad en tiempo real y no tener que estar actualizando la página

Comment: En ajax no existe tiempo real, puedes usar setInterval para actualizar cada momento recomiendo cada minuto, hay otras alternativas como, por ejemplo, supongamos que cada vez que entra el cliente, se obtiene la fecha inicial y con un javascript cada segundo ir sacando la diferencia de tiempo, apartir de la fecha inicial, el php solo debe retornar los datos iniciales, pero javascript debe hacer las operaciones, esto también para que no te consuma recursos del servidor y usar los recursos del cliente(navegador)

Comment: Haciendo lo anterior si se agrega un nuevo usuario, no se podría mostrar, a menos que tengas otro setInterval para actualizar cada minuto, así tendría algo sencillo. también puedes usar websocket, para que cuando un cliente se registre, se actualice esa vista de todos los clientes conectados.

Comment: @DarckBlezzer Gracias por tu respuesta pero eso no es lo que quiero, sólo quiero que mientras pasen las horas esos minutos se actualicen automáticamente y no tenga que actualizar la página

Comment: El problema de usar setInterval sin ajax es que si alguno de los usuarios se desconecta y luego de 5min se vuelve a conectar la fecha cambiaria por tanto el calculo del lado del cliente donde iba sumando arbitrariamente los minutos ya tendria un bug.

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas son fecha de creación, no de inicio de sesión

Comment: pero fijate si son de creacion si puedes usar el setInterval, solo con el inconveniente que los usuarios nuevos no van a salir reflejados, al no ser que cargues la tabla con los datos nuevos

Comment: Cuando dibujas la tabla le pones en alguna fila un atributo con el id del usuario que vas a mostrar dentro, creas un setInterval que cada x tiempo haga un ajax y pase esos ids, en el lado del servidor recibes ese ajax y buscas los usuarios que no tengan ese id, es decir los nuevos y devuelves toda su informacion, luego en el lado del cliente recibes la respuesta y dibujas las nuevas filas. Mientras tienes otro setInterval que va incrementando los valores de los minutos

Comment: Leí tu pregunta y no entendí lo que quieres hacer... tampoco veo dónde está la columna `start_session`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podes marcar el `TD` con la fecha de creación en formato timeStamp y luego hacer los cáculos necesarios cada N segundos con un intervalo javascript.

```
<table class="table">
<tr><td><b>Minutes</b></td><td><b>User - Points</b></td></tr>
<?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    while(mysql_fetch_array($res){
      $start_session = $row['start_session'];

      $start_date = new DateTime($start_session);
      $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($date));
      $minutes = $since_start->days * 24 * 60;
      $minutes += $since_start->h * 60;
      $minutes += $since_start->i;

 ?>
 <tr>
  <td class="minutos" data-creation="<?php echo $start_date->getTimestamp();?>">
      <?php echo $minutes." min"; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
      <?php echo $row['users']." - ".$row['points']." points"; ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
<?php
  }
 }
?>
</table>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var losTiempos = [...document.getElementsByClassName("minutos")];
  var actualizaTiempos = function() {
    losTiempos.forEach(function(element) {
      var creation = element.getAttribute('data-creation');
      var timeStamp = ~~(Date.now() / 1000);
      var timeDiff  = Math.abs(timeStamp - creation);
      var minutosDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
      element.innerText =  minutosDiff + " mins" ;
      //console.log(creation, timeDiff, minutosDiff + " min " );
    });
  };
  var intervalID = setInterval(actualizaTiempos, 1000 * 60);
});

</script>
```

una muestra con datos estáticos:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var losTiempos = [...document.getElementsByClassName("minutos")];
  var actualizaTiempos = function() {
    losTiempos.forEach(function(element) {
      var creation = element.getAttribute('data-creation');
      var timeStamp = ~~(Date.now() / 1000);
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(timeStamp - creation);
      var minutosDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
      element.innerText = minutosDiff + " min ";
      //console.log(creation, timeDiff, minutosDiff + " mins" );
    });
  };
  actualizaTiempos();
  var intervalID = setInterval(actualizaTiempos, 1000 * 30);
});
```

```css
td {padding:5px; border-right: 1px red solid}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Minutes</b></td>
    <td><b>User - Points</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="minutos" data-creation="1533139200">1948 min </td>
    <td>anna - 85.00 points</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="minutos" data-creation="1533133380">2045 min </td>
    <td>alfred - 35.00 points</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="minutos" data-creation="1533153840">1704 min </td>
    <td>georgy - 125.00 points</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="minutos" data-creation="1533162600">1558 min </td>
    <td>linda - 42.00 points</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="minutos" data-creation="1533123300">2213 min </td>
    <td>alex - 76.00 points</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="minutos" data-creation="1533130140">2099 min </td>
    <td>john - 94.00 points </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="minutos" data-creation="1533148020">1801 min </td>
    <td>hugo - 75.30 points </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Funciona genial, sólo una consulta, estoy revisando tu código y me gustaría que me expliques el significado de la línea `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {` y también el porqué poner el array con puntos suspensivos al inicio en la variable `losTiempos` y la variable timeStamp con este símbolo `~~(`

Comment: La primer línea es equivalente al [`jQuery(document).ready`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/177716/81450), los tres puntitos es el [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator), que usado entre corchetes `[...]` transforma la lista de `getElementsByClassName` a un array para poder hacer un `foreach`.  El `~~` es un doble `NOT` binario para convertir de `float` a `integer`, en un tiempo era más rápido que el `Math.floor` hoy creo que es lo mismo (habría que correr algunos tests).

Comment: Genial, y qué pasaría si las filas y celdas vengan de una respuesta AJAX? Lo he intentado usar en ese caso y no está funcionando, habría algo que añadir?

Comment: mientras mantengan el formato y estructura debería tomarlo, pero sin verlo no sabría decirte